# Downloading Insight data with automated background process

Tags: console, facebook-insights

I am building a c# console application that will run as background automated process running weekly (or may be daily) to download page level and post level insight data. I have one facebook account that manages several facebook pages, I need to get data for all of those pages.

I still could not figure out how do I get a access token from my console application and where I could send request for Page level and Post level Insights ?

From the UI I can download CSv file, can I do that using API too or I will  have to download JSON string and then parse it ?

thanks for your help